# I have a slight tick in my Jquery slide?

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://www.nicholaslawson.com ... if you click on any of the nav buttons on the side it will take you there buuuut there is every so slightly a tick ... I believe it to be a margin or padding problem but I dont exactly know how to solve this issue. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please elaborate the problem...because I cant see any tick

Comment: i see the tick at the end, it seems to happen less when i remove the padding size of 5%/20% you have set on your container divs.

Comment: that is probably it from what I know from vague recollections of a previous problem similar to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two thoughts just from a quick look at the code that you might want to try:

- Try putting the section id's on the H1 header tags instead of the divs.
- Try changing the easing function that jquery is using.  Instead of 'easeInOutExpo', try 'swing' and see if that makes a difference.

Other than that, your code looks very similar to code that I have that scrolls smoothly without any 'ticks'.

Comment: I will try to change it to swing and if that does not work Ill try the id's on H1's instead of divs.